# Extracting text from documents of unknown content type

Tags: java, content-type, text-extraction, apache-tika

is there a parser for `application/octet-stream` type within Apache Tika? I suppose it's a non-parsable stream.

I just need to parse ODS documents, MS documents and PDF files. It seems that  `new Tika( ).parseToString(file);`  is enough. But I can't figure out what happens when the content type is not detected - > `application/octet-stream` is default. If I have a chance to extract text from those documents that are one of those types, but contentType detector didn't detect their type.

What else should I try instead of returning document to the user telling him that it is not supported format.

Or is really a resulting `application/octet-stream` content type a signal that we can't read this ? Or "you must figure out your own way how to deal with this" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the detector doesn't know what the file is, it'll return *application/octet-stream*

And if the detector doesn't know what it is, then Tika won't be able to pick a suitable Parser for it. (You'll end up with the EmptyParser which does nothing)

If you can, pass in the name of your file when you do the detection and parsing, as that'll help with the detection in some cases:

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.set(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, filename);
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
parser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());
```

Also, it's worth checking the supported formats part of the Tika website to ensure that the documents you have are ones where there's a Parser - http://tika.apache.org/0.9/formats.html

If your documents are in a format that isn't currently supported, then you have two choices (neither immediate fixes). One is to help write a new parser (requires finding a suitable Java library for the format). The other is to use a command line based parser (requires finding an executable for your platform that can do the xhtml generation, then wiring that in)

Comment: Thank you, and how is it done in Tika when you have a range of mime types and range of file extensions that you want to work with only ? By default it loads all the mime types and file extensions from the tika-mimetypes.xml file and it is loaded into MimeTypes.types and MimeTypes.registry . Do I have to create my own tika-mimetypes.xml ? or can I load a different file with mime types definitions? There is only MimeTypes.getDefaultMimeTypes() that loads the file.

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove detection for some mime types that are in by default? If so, at the moment you only easy-ish option is to customise tika-mimetypes.xml and have your version come earlier up the classpath so it's used in preference. If you have some new mimetypes you want detecting, easiest is to submit a patch so we include it upstream!

Comment: I want to remove detection for 90% of mime types. Only mime types corresponding to these extensions html,doc,docx,odt,txt,rtf,srt,sub,pdf,ods,odp,xls,ppt,msg should be detected. The other documents that have different mime type should be denied. I use ContainerAwareDetector and MimeTypes detector as a fallback detector... I hope it's a good choice

Comment: I think you'll want a custom tika-mimetypes.xml, and a TikaConfig instance where you specify the MimeType object build from the custom mapping file.